# Error in PHP script , undefined variable

Tags: php

```
<?PHP
include_once("connection.php");

$username = $_POST['txtUsername'];

$query = "SELECT * FROM cart_management WHERE UserName = '$username' ORDER BY Cart_Name ASC"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data)
?>
```

[image]

Please help me to cater this , i am unable to fix this issue ?

Comment: post your the code of request

Comment: Before the while loop, set $data as an empty array ( $data = [];)

Comment: Please review [Ask].  Avoid posting images, they are not searchable. Copy the text of the error messages directly into your post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should first check for `txtUsername`, that's your first notice in the screenshot. Secondly you should declare`$data` as empty array before using it in the `while` loop, else it results in second notice in your screenshot:

```
if($_POST['txtUsername'] && $_POST['txtUsername'] != '') {
    $username = $_POST['txtUsername'];
    $data = [];
    $query = "SELECT * FROM cart_management WHERE UserName = '$username' ORDER BY Cart_Name ASC"; 

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to check the the data you are sending is with the same index `txtUsername` that must be same . (check where you are calling `cartRetrive.php` api)

and the second error is for undefined variable.

you are trying to use `$data[]` before you declare it.

```
<?PHP
include_once("connection.php");

$username = $_POST['txtUsername']; // check the index from where you are calling  cartRetrive.php

$query = "SELECT * FROM cart_management WHERE UserName = '$username' ORDER BY Cart_Name ASC"; 

$result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);

car data[] = array();// declare variable here

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $data[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($data)
?>
```